# Iterating over object instances of a given class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Given a class that keeps a registry of its Objects:

```
class Person(object):
   __registry = []

   def __init__(self, name):
       self.__registry.append(self)
       self.name = name
```

How would I make the following code work (without using Person.__registry):

```
for personobject in Person:
    print personobject
```

While researching I found a hint that one could go for a `__metaclass__` with a `__getitem__`-method. Any ideas how this would look like?

Comment: ehh don't make an ugly hack look pretty.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make your class object iterable with a simple metaclass.

```
class IterRegistry(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._registry)

class Person(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
    _registry = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name
```

(I have also changed `__registry` to `_registry` to make it easier to access from the metaclass).
Then,

```
>>> p = Person('John')
>>> p2 = Person('Mary')
>>> for personobject in Person:
...     print personobject
...
<person.Person object at 0x70410>
<person.Person object at 0x70250>
```

Comment: Really nice tip: I didn't know this one :)

Comment: Why doesn't this work with just putting the def __iter__ in the Person class? Just wondering.

Comment: @Paolo Putting __iter__ in the Person class makes Person instances iterable, putting it in the metaclass makes the Person class itself iterable, which is what we want here.

Comment: Hi, I have tested this piece of code in Python 3.6.0  Anaconda 64-bit and it does not work. I fixed the print statement but you get a TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable. I am a newby in Python but I guess this is probably because the specifications for an iterable object have been changed in Python 3.6.

Comment: _registery doesn't get updated when you delete instances of the class though.

Comment: @Athanassios, for Python 3 see [Iterating over object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362984/2556118) or [Make class iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434400/python-make-class-iterable).

Answer (score 17):

First, do not use double `__` names.  They're reserved for use by Python.  If you want "private" use single `_`.

Second, keep this kind of thing as simple as possible.  Don't waste a lot of time and energy on something complex.  This is a simple problem, keep the code as simple as possible to get the job done.

```
class Person(object):
    _registry = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name

for p in Person._registry:
    print p
```

Comment: The point is that the _registry solution *is* the simplest possible way to do this.  Anything else is just trying to "put lipstick on a pig".

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with:

```
for item in Person.__registry:
    print(item)
```

Comment: thats obvious... but i would like to make it work like: for item in Classname ... (just for the beauty of it...)

Comment: you need to make your class iterable then, I guess