# python: return value from __new__

Tags: python, constructor

**EDIT**

I actually called `object.__new__(cls)`, and I didn't realize that by this I built an object of class cls! Thanks for pointing this out to me.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

The documentation says

> If **new**() does not return an
>   instance of cls, then the new
>   instance’s **init**() method will not
>   be invoked.

However, when I return `object.__new__()` from `cls.__new__()`, the `__init__()` is still invoked. I wouldn't consider an instance of object to qualify as an instance of cls. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your observation:

```
>>> class cls(object):
...   def __new__(cls):
...     return object.__new__(object)
...   def __init__(self):
...     print 'in __init__'
... 
>>> x = cls()
>>>
```

As you see, `cls.__init__` isn't executing.

How **are** you calling `object.__new__` (and, btw, *why* are you?-).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :( You are right..
What's the proper thing to do? Should I delete the question?

Comment: I'm using __new__ to implement enumerator (see this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588996/python-enumeration-class-for-orm-purposes)

Comment: @max, just clarify that you're calling `object.__new__(cls)` by editing your question -- **that** `cls` argument makes a `cls` instance, which is why `cls.__init__` is then called on it, as it must.