# Python: Make class iterable

Tags: python, syntax, attributes, static-methods, loops

I have inherited a project with many large classes constituent of nothing but class objects (integers, strings, etc). I'd like to be able to check if an attribute is present without needed to define a list of attributes manually.

Is it possible to make a python *class* iterable itself using the standard syntax? That is, I'd like to be able to iterate over all of a class's attributes using `for attr in Foo:` (or even `if attr in Foo`) without needing to create an instance of the class first. I think I can do this by defining `__iter__`, but so far I haven't quite managed what I'm looking for.

I've achieved some of what I want by adding an `__iter__` method like so:

```
class Foo:
    bar = "bar"
    baz = 1
    @staticmethod
    def __iter__():
        return iter([attr for attr in dir(Foo) if attr[:2] != "__"])
```

However, this does not quite accomplish what I'm looking for:

> ```
> >>> for x in Foo:
> ...     print(x)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: 'classobj' object is not iterable
> ```

Even so, this works:

> ```
> >>> for x in Foo.__iter__():
> ...     print(x)
> bar
> baz
> ```

Comment: If you want to check whether an attribute is present, the way to do that is [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr). You don't need to make your class iterable.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add the `__iter__` to the metaclass instead of the class itself (assuming Python 2.x):

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = "bar"
    baz = 1
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __iter__(self):
            for attr in dir(self):
                if not attr.startswith("__"):
                    yield attr
```

For Python 3.x, use

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith("__"):
                yield attr

class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    bar = "bar"
    baz = 1
```

Comment: Nice. Please could you explain why the OP's approach doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: @aix: The reason OP's approach doesn't work is that the `__iter__` method only works for *instances* of the class. This bumps the `__iter__` method up to instances of the metaclass, i.e. the class.

Comment: @aix: As other magic methods, `__iter__` is looked up in the name space of the type of the object rather than in the object's name space itself.  I did not really find this explained in the Python docs, but it can be easily seen in the [source code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Objects/abstract.c?view=markup) (search for the definition of `PyObject_GetIter()`).

Comment: Could someone explain why it doesn't work, when writing the __iter__() method as a `@classmethod` on the `Foo` class? @nmichaels answer doesn't explain this I think.  
`
@classmethod
def __iter__(cls):
    for x in xrange(10):
        yield x
`

Comment: @trudolf: [Special methods are looked up on the type of the instance, not on the instance itself](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup).  If the instance is a class, this means the special method is looked up on the metaclass, not the class itself.

Answer (score 14):

this is how we make a class object iterable. provide the class with a **iter** and a next() method, then you can iterate over class attributes or their values.you can leave the next() method if you want to, or you can define next() and raise StopIteration on some condition.

e.g:

```
class Book(object):
      def __init__(self,title,author):
          self.title = title
          self.author = author

      def __iter__(self):
          for each in self.__dict__.values():
              yield each

>>> book  = Book('The Mill on the Floss','George Eliot')
>>> for each in book: each
...
'George Eliot'
'The Mill on the Floss'
```

this class iterates over attribute value of class Book.
A class object can be made iterable by providing it with a **getitem** method too.
e.g:

```
class BenTen(object):
    def __init__(self, bentenlist):
        self.bentenlist = bentenlist
        
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if index <5:
            return self.bentenlist[index]
        else:
            raise IndexError('this is high enough')

>>> bt_obj = BenTen([x for x in range(15)])
>>>for each in bt_obj:each
...
0
1
2
3
4
```

now when the object of BenTen class is used in a for-in loop, getitem is called with succesively higher index value, till it raises IndexError.

Comment: This iterates over the attributes of an _instance_ of a class (i.e. the `book` in `book = Book(...)`); the question is about iterating over the _class_ attributes directly (i.e. the `Book` in `class Book(object):`).

Comment: Although this is not the answer to OP's question, it helped me because I was looking for this when searching for iterable class.

Comment: It should be __iter__() and __next__()?

Answer (score 8):

You can iterate over the class's unhidden attributes with `for attr in (elem for elem in dir(Foo) if elem[:2] != '__')`.

A less horrible way to spell that is:

```
def class_iter(Class):
    return (elem for elem in dir(Class) if elem[:2] != '__')
```

then

```
for attr in class_iter(Foo):
    pass
```

Comment: I must admit I prefer this solution which looks more pythonic than the one of OP. But has it's not solve his problem I did not +1

Answer (score 0):

```
class MetaItetaror(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(
            filter(
                lambda k: not k[0].startswith('__'),
                cls.__dict__.iteritems()
            )
        )


class Klass:
    __metaclass__ = MetaItetaror

    iterable_attr_names = {'x', 'y', 'z'}
    x = 5
    y = 6
    z = 7


for v in Klass:
    print v
```

Answer (score 0):

An instance of [`enum.Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) happens to be iterable, and while it is not a general solution, it is a reasonable option for some use cases:

```
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    bar = "qux"
    baz = 123

>>> print(*Foo)
Foo.bar Foo.baz

names = [m.name for m in Foo]
>>> print(*names)
bar baz

values = [m.value for m in Foo]
print(*values)
>>> qux 123
```

As with `.__dict__`, the order of iteration using this `Enum` based approach is the same as the order of definition.

Comment: This completely changes the behavior of the class and all its attributes. Making the class iterable is a minor side effect. It's not a solution to the general problem of making classes iterable.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica First, that's a weird username. Second, I have now updated the answer to mention that this approach is not a general solution. It is nevertheless useful for some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

### You can make class members iterable within just a single line.

Despite the easy and compact code there are two mayor features included, additionally:

1. Type checking allows using additional class members not to be iterated.
2. The technique is also working if (public) class methods are defined. The proposals above using the "__" string checking filtering method propably fail in such cases.

```
# How to make class members iterable in a single line within Python (O. Simon, 14.4.2022)
# Includes type checking to allow additional class members not to be iterated

class SampleVector():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name 
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return [value for value in self.__dict__.values() if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float)].__iter__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    v = SampleVector(4, 5, "myVector")
    print (f"The content of sample vector '{v.name}' is:\n")
    for m in v:
        print(m)
```

This solution is fairly close and inspired by answer 12 from Hans Ginzel and Vijay Shanker.