# python built-in function type, how to define a member function for the new type?

Tags: python

In the reference document: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type
It showed how to define a member variable
    X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))

But how to define a member function, so the class can equivalent to:

```
class X(object):
    a = 1
    def get_a(self):
        return self.a
```

This question is originated by adding iterable feature to a given custom enum type.
In my project, there is an old custom enum type here:

```
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    """ Contruct an enum """
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    reverse = dict((value, key) for key, value in enums.items())
    enums['reverse_mapping'] = reverse
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

It can be used like:

```
MY_COLORS = enum(RED=0,BLUE=1)
```

But enums defined by this method cannot be used as iterable object in 'for in' statement. I hope to add a member function to return keys, values and items of the enums. Then I can do something like this:

```
[item for item in MY_COLORS.keys()]
```

**Answer for python3:**

```
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    """ Contruct an enum """
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    reverse = dict((value, key) for key, value in enums.items())
    key_names = list(enums.keys())
    enums['reverse_mapping'] = reverse        
    @classmethod
    def keys(klass):
        return key_names 
    enums['keys'] = keys
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (tested in *Python 2.7*)

```
def enum(*sequential, **named):
    """ Contruct an enum """
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    reverse = dict((value, key) for key, value in enums.items())
    key_names = enums.keys()
    enums['reverse_mapping'] = reverse        
    @classmethod
    def keys(klass):
       return key_names 
    enums['keys'] = keys
    return type('Enum', (), enums)
```

You want to add a `classmethod` to the enums dict. That is what the `@classmethod` decorator does.

Running this does:

```
>>> MY_COLORS = enum(RED=0, BLUE=1)
>>> MY_COLORS.keys()
['BLUE', 'RED']
```

If you want to be able to iterate over `MY_COLORS` itself, you need to add a metaclass as in this question: [Python: Is it possible to make a class iterable using the standard syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434400/python-is-it-possible-to-make-a-class-iterable-using-the-standard-syntax)

Comment: I tested it, the actual result I got is _dict_keys(['BLUE', 'keys', 'reverse_mapping', 'RED'])_  How can I get rid of _keys_ and _reverse_mapping_, which beat the enum's original requirement?

Comment: you didn't change the code, did you? The code you post won't print _['BLUE', 'RED']_. However, I found to use _named.keys()_ instead of _enums.keys()_ at line 5 can fix it, but I still don't understand why _enums.keys()_ not working here...

Comment: i did change the code, but only slightly: i moved the line `key_names = enums.keys()` up, so that i capture the names *before* we add `reverse_mapping` and `keys`. so yes, it does work now. source: ran it in the interpreter to check...

Comment: problem with using `named.keys()` is that the `sequential` parts won't be added...

Comment: I figured out your code works in Python2.7. I was using Python3.3, where it has different output. :/

Answer (score 1):

A similar but shorter approch of @Eugeny Loy idea would be with a lambda:

```
>>> X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1, get_a=lambda self: self.a))
>>> x = X()
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.get_a()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your class an iterable class you need to give it a `next()` method - It is a very good idea to give to base your class on `object` as well - you can then use it as you are suggesting.

Comment: Or just implement __iter__