# TypeError: INT object is not iterable while defining a custom iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tying to make my custom class iterable by defining an iterator based on Vijay Shankar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434400/python-make-class-iterable):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

class MyClass():
    id = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self, location = None):
        self.id = next(MyClass.id)
        self.location = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1, 2)).tolist()

    def __iter__(self):
        for _ in self.__dict__.values():
            yield _

def create():
    objects = []
    objects.append(MyClass())
    counter = 1
    while counter != 20:
        new_object = MyClass()
        objects.append(new_object)
        counter = counter + 1
    return objects

objects = create()
objects = [[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in objects]
```

However, I still get this error

```
objects = [[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in objects]
TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix this problem?

Edit:

Currently, this is what the iterator returns:

```
>>> print([x for x in create()[0]])
[20, [[0.2552026126490259, 0.48489389169530417]]]
```

How should one revise it so that it returns like below?

```
>>> print([x for x in create()[0]])
[20, [0.2552026126490259, 0.48489389169530417]]
```

Comment: This code actually fails with ``TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable``. The problem is that iterating ``MyClass`` yields a flat id and a nested location – what should happen instead is something that you have to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one too many iterations:

```
[[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in objects]
```

I count 3 `for`s Meaning 3 iterations. The first iterations would be the list from `create()` into the `MyClass()` objects. The second iteration would be the attributes of each `MyClass()` The third would attempt to iterate over location/id/whatever other properties the class has. This isn't safe because the property id (int) is not an iterator.

List[MyClass] -> MyClass -> Properties of MyClass (id/location) -> ERROR

Your iterator is working. Here's an iteration over just a single `MyClass()`:

```py
print([x for x in create()[0]])
>>> [20, [[0.2552026126490259, 0.48489389169530417]]]
```

If you want to expand a list of your class (instead of just one as I did above)

```py
my_classes = create()
objects = [[attribute for attribute in my_class] for my_class in my_classes]
print(objects)
>>>[[0, [[0.7226935825759357, 0.18522688980137658]]], [1, [[0.1660964810272717, 0.016810136422152677]]], [2, [[0.1611089351209548, 0.3935547119768953]]], [3, [[0.4589556901947873, 0.18405198063215056]]], [4, [[0.811343515881961, 0.6123114388786854]]], [5, [[0.38830918188777996, 0.23119360704055836]]], [6, [[0.3269834811013743, 0.3608326475799025]]], [7, [[0.9971686351479419, 0.7054058805215702]]], [8, [[0.11316919241038192, 0.07453424664431929]]], [9, [[0.5548059787590179, 0.062422711183232615]]], [10, [[0.38567389514423267, 0.659106105987059]]], [11, [[0.973277039327461, 0.2821071201116454]]], [12, [[0.16566758369419543, 0.3010363002131601]]], [13, [[0.923317671409532, 0.30016022638587536]]], [14, [[0.9757923181511164, 0.5888806462517852]]], [15, [[0.5582498753119571, 0.27190786180188264]]], [16, [[0.28120075553258217, 0.6873211952682786]]], [17, [[0.7016575026994472, 0.5820325771264436]]], [18, [[0.5815482608888624, 0.22729004063915448]]], [19, [[0.2009082164070768, 0.11317171355184519]]]]
```

Additionally. You may as well use `yield from` here. As you're yielding another iterable.

```py
class MyClass():
    id = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self, location = None):
        self.id = next(MyClass.id)
        self.location = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1, 2)).tolist()

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.__dict__.valies()
```

EDIT:

Per your question on location being a nested list instead of a list just throw away that extra dimension when you assign to self.location.

```py
print(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1, 2)).tolist())
>>> [[0.3649653171602294, 0.8447097505387996]]
print(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1, 2)).tolist()[0])
[0.247024738276844, 0.9303441776787809]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need the result of the iteration be something like `[[id, [num1, num2]], ...]`. However, it has one extra pair of brackets, say, `[[id, [[num1, num2]]], ...]`. How can I resolve this, as well?

Comment: Could you append your post with an example that shows a list of two classes and then your desired output? I'm not clear on what you want.

Comment: Please check the edit applied to the question.

Comment: @User see my edit. np.random.uniform() seems to return one more dimension than you need. Just select the first entry.