# TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable - Iterating over object instances

Tags: python, iterable

I am working on a project and I would like to make one of my classes iterable. To the best of my knowledge I can do that with using metaclass.

First of all I would like to understand how metaclass works. Therefore I would like to present my own practicing example where I made a Car class. So here I would like to make my Car class objects iterable then I would like to print the names of them in the main function.

The code example is the following:

```
__author__ = 'mirind4'

class IterableCar(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__name__)

class Car(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterableCar

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


if __name__=='__main__':

    car1 = Car('Mercedes')
    car2 = Car('Toyota')
    for cars in Car:
        print (cars.name)
```

But unfortunately I got an TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Would you be so kind as to tell me where I do the mistake in my code? So far I have checked similar problem-questions over this site and internet but I do not know what the problem is. I am using python 3.4.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `for cars in Car`. Car is a class definition. What do you expect that to do? Did you mean to put `car1` and `car2` into a list and iterate over that? (I see that you have something at the top of your question about "making a class iterable" but it's not clear what you want. `Car` doesn't seem to represent any kind of collection.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist -- I think that OP wants it to yield `C - A - R` ... Interesting concept making an iterable _class_...

Comment: @mgilson I would actually guess that the OP wants it to return every instance so far created, which I doubt is possible, but we shall see.

Comment: In Python 3, you define a metaclass with `class Car(metaclass=IterableCar)`, not with the `__metaclass__` attribute.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's possible, in the sense that you just need to maintain such a list yourself with the class's `__new__` method.

Comment: @chepner Would that catch all the subclasses and mixins and such?

Comment: Assuming the metaclass is providing the definition of `__new__`, I believe so.

Comment: Two-BitAlchemist is right, I want it to return every instance so far created. Sorry for my unclear explanation...

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine with the solution below. I appreciate your all help and comments! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, making a class object iterable by using a metaclass works just fine:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class IterableCar(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls.__name__)

class Car(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterableCar

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


if __name__=='__main__':

    car1 = Car('Mercedes')
    car2 = Car('Toyota')
    for cars in Car:
        print (cars)
```

Results in:

```
mgilson$ python ~/sandbox/test.py 
C
a
r
```

---

Here's an example where I actually track the cars generated:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import weakref

class IterableCar(type):

    _cars = weakref.WeakSet()

    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._cars)

    def add_car(cls, car):
        cls._cars.add(car)


class Car(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterableCar

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__class__.add_car(self)
        self.name = name


if __name__=='__main__':

    car1 = Car('Mercedes')
    car2 = Car('Toyota')
    for cars in Car:
        print (cars.name)
```

Note that if you're using python3.x, to use a metaclass you do:

```
class Car(metaclass=IterableCar):
    ...
```

Rather than:

```
class Car(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterableCar
```

which likely explains the problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: The `weakref` module can be used to fix the memory leak.

Comment: @DanD. -- Yep  `weakref.WeakSet` is probably the easiest to use object in there that could help here, but that's out of the scope of this question I think ... (since we don't really even know what OP is trying to do...)

Comment: @DanD. -- Updated with a `WeakSet`

Comment: @DanD. Unfortunately I do not understand why the program had memory-leak problem without the weakref module. Is Garbage Collector not working in this situation? To be honest I am still a bit beginner at this topic, sorry for that. Would you be so kind as to give me a short explanation of it? (I know what memory-leak is, but I do not know where is (was) it in mgilson's code). Many Thanks!

Comment: @mirind4 -- If you keep a list of instances at the class level, there will always be a reference to every instance every created.  Because of this, the reference count can never drop to 0 and so the object will never be able to be garbage collected.  It's possible that is your desired behavior.  With the `WeakSet`, when an object goes out of scope, it will be garbage collected and the class will stop tracking it.

Comment: @mgilson Thank you again for the explanation, it helped my thinking of this a lot! I am of the opinion that I should look for some articles and information about this "reference count" thing! There is always something to learn! Have a nice day! ;)

Comment: @mgilson I am still wondering this example, and unfortunately I am not completely understand it, sorry for it! :\ If you have a little time could you  help me, please? In order to make the class iterable I have to make a metaclass. Till this point I got it. But when I iterate over them in the main function I use the "Car" class as the iterable instead of IterableCar class. What's exactly happening here? I've read articles of this metaclass thing, but it's still a bit vague for me :\ And again, sorry for my nooby questions...

Answer (score 3):

To track instances of the class that are created, we'll start by adding a `_cars` attribute to each the class created by the metaclass. This will be  set of weak references, so that the class itself does not prevent unused instances from being garbage-collected.

```
class IterableCar(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['_cars'] = weaker.WeakSet()
        return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)
```

To add the instances, we'll override `__call__`. Essentially, this is where you put code that you would ordinarily put in `__new__` or `__init__` when defining the class itself.

```
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        rv = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls._cars.add(rv)
        return rv
```

And to make the class iterable by iterating over its set of instances,

```
   def __iter__(self):
       return iter(self._cars)
```

Any class using `IterableCar` will automatically track its instances.

```
class Car(metaclass=IterableCar):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

car1 = Car('Mercedes')
car2 = Car('Toyota')
for cars in Car:
    print(cars.name)
```

Comment: Nice.  Now if you just make it a WeakSet to fix the "memory-leak", you'll be all set :-).

Comment: And, I suppose for completeness, you'll want to add the `__iter__` as well (which would iterate return `iter(cls._cars)`)

Comment: @chepner thank you for your detailed answer, I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error appear when a decorator was expecting a Tuple and I passed in a single element without a trailing comma.

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@authentication_classes((CustomAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((AdminPermission))
def order_attached_documents_from_order_uuid(request):
    # ...
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

After I changed `@permission_classes((AdminPermission))` to `@permission_classes((AdminPermission,))` everything started working just fine.