# Iterating over a custom class. TypeError: object is not iterable

Tags: python, iterator

I am creating a custom class for my project which is a recursive list of dictionaries. The attribute `my_list` is a list of dictionaries in which case I want to iterate over each of the keys, in each of the dictionaries, within the one object.

The code below is my current attempt. I have seen this solution [TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable - Iterating over object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362148/typeerror-type-object-is-not-iterable-iterating-over-object-instances) which gets the same error message but the difference is I want to iterate within a class not over all the objects of a particular class.

```py
class List_of_dicts:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def add(self, item: dict):
        self.my_list.append(item)


l = List_of_dicts()
l.add({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
l.add({'c': 3, 'd': 4})

for obj in l:
    print(obj.key)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'List_of_dicts' object is not iterable
```

I expect the iteration to be over the keys: a, b, c, d, in that order.

How do I implement the iterative behaviour which will allow me to iterate over a class like this?

Comment: You should iterate `l.my_list` not `l` itself.

Comment: you have to implement the __iter__ function for the class List_of_dicts

Comment: and also the __next__ function