# Printing a list of object values out of a list of objects in python

Tags: python

I want to apply some statistics on a list of objects of a class. These objects have 6 values (open, high, low, close, volume and timestamp) each. Lets say i want to print a list with just the volume of each object. How can i do this?

Comment: I think this post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739882/iterating-over-object-instances-of-a-given-class-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method to your class definition:

```
def returnVolume(self):
    return self.volume
```

In theory, this should `return` the volume of your objects when you call the function upon them.

Another way which would work would be to use list comprehensions (see the other answer).