# iterating over a set of class instances

Tags: python, class, set, instance

let's say we have the following class Boy:

```
class Boy():

def __init__(self, name, hair, friend=None):
    self.name = name
    self.hair = hair
    self.friend = friend
```

and we have some instances of this class and we want to iterate it, and change attributes on these instances while iterating.
for example:

```
ben = Boy("Ben", "red")
sam = Boy("Sam", "black")
roger = Boy("Roger", "yellow", sam)
boys = {ben, sam}
for boy in boys:
    boy = roger.friend
```

The above method only change the attribute of the pointer "boy" and not the instance in the set. What's the best way to approcah this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over object instances of a given class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739882/iterating-over-object-instances-of-a-given-class-in-python)

Comment: you want `boy.friend = roger`, I think (although your precise intention isn't so clear)

Comment: @RajatMishra the link you posted doesn't have anything to do with my question. I want to iterate over a *set* and change the instances inside it, not to iterate over an instance attributes.

Answer (score -1):

For changing attribute of element in the set

Your code below assign the `ref of roger's friend to the ref of boy
Actually this did nothing.

```py
for boy in boys:
    boy = roger.friend
```

Here is the method to change attribute of element in a set iteratively

```
for boy in boys:
    boy.hair = 'green'
    boy.friend = roger

# Check results
for boy in boys:
    print('----')
    print(boy.name)
    print(boy.hair)
    print(boy.friend.name)
```

Comment: That's not what i meant at all. I want to change the attributes of the instances inside the set..